# Cannot call method push of undefined (when it's defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm using Node.js and mongoose to create a backend for an app where users can friend each other.

**Schema**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    name : String,
    nick: String, 
    reg_id: String,
    friends: {
      type: Array,
      'default': []
    }
   });
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DB');
  module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

**Request**

```
exports.addfriend = function(reg_id,friend,callback) {

  user.find({reg_id:reg_id},function(err,guy){   

    // found the user, now add his friend
    user.find({name:friend}, function(err,friendFound){
      console.log("trying to add friend to:"+guy)
      console.log("his current friends:"+guy.friends)

      guy.friends.push(friendFound.reg_id)
        callback({'response':guy.name+' is now friends with '+friendFound.name});
    })
  }); 
}
```

**Console**

```
trying to add friend to:{ _id: 5483d2c76dd64ee412bfe865,
  name: 'Hello',
  nick: 'hey',
  reg_id: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  __v: 0,
  friends: [] }
his current friends:undefined

C:\..\config\requests.js:82
      guy.friends.push(friendFound.reg_id)
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Why is the array showing up as defined when its defined in the schema AND I'm retriving the right user (guy) ? Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the object `friendFound` with data or null?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your guy object is actually a string of JSON rather than a JSON object. Try running a JSON parse on it

```
exports.addfriend = function(reg_id,friend,callback) {

  user.find({reg_id:reg_id},function(err,guy){   
    guy = JSON.parse(guy); //ADD THIS
    // found the user, now add his friend
    user.find({name:friend}, function(err,friendFound){
      console.log("trying to add friend to:"+guy)
      console.log("his current friends:"+guy.friends)

      guy.friends.push(friendFound.reg_id)
        callback({'response':guy.name+' is now friends with '+friendFound.name});
    })
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Got an error when trying to parse the object ID generated by mongo

`undefined:1
{ _id: 5483d815ff8b74480f7dcf85,
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arin\Documents\reference\node-chat\node_mod
ules\config\requests.js:76:16)`

Comment: The JSON is invalid, the api is giving that id without quotes because it is a hexadecimal number. JSON parse is seeing it is a string without quotes so it throws an error. Try putting a single quote after _id: and one before the first comma and see if that fixes the problem.